# Trying to query a redshift within SELECT statement

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, amazon-redshift, user-defined-functions

Current `table1`:

```
col1
-------------
schema.table1
schema.table2
schema.table3
```

Desired `table1`:

```
col1           col2
------------------------------------------------------------
schema.table1  value of (select count(*) from schema.table1)
schema.table2  value of (select count(*) from schema.table1)
schema.table3  value of (select count(*) from schema.table1)
```

It is not working, I tried using function too, but function doesn't allow to use 'FROM'

```
select col1, (select count(*) from col1) 
from table1
```

I am trying to create this query in redshift. Can anyone please help me out?

Comment: You are going to need a stored procedure for this.  You indicated that you tried this - can you show this code?

Comment: "SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at or near "$1""                                                                                                                                                                                           
 ``` create or replace procedure view.sp_count(tablename varchar(25))
    language plpgsql as
$$
DECLARE 
 count_calc     BIGINT;
BEGIN
 count_calc:= (SELECT count(*) from tablename);
 
END;
$$;                                                                                                                                  
 ```

Answer (score 0):

To perform this task you will need a stored procedure AND a defined cursor.  The stored procedure allows for looping and the cursor provides the ability to execute a newly created statement (dynamic querying).

For example:

Create the starting materials, 3 tables and a table that references these tables.

```
create table foo as (select 1 as A);
create table goo as (select 2 as A);
create table hoo as (select 3 as A);

create table tabs as (select 'foo' as tab union all select 'goo' union all select 'hoo');
```

Next define the stored procedure the will create the dynamic SQL

```
CREATE OR REPLACE procedure count_tabs(curs1 INOUT refcursor)
AS
$$
DECLARE 
  row record;
  statement varchar := '';
  union_needed BOOL := false;
BEGIN
  for row in select tab from tabs LOOP
    IF union_needed THEN
      statement := statement || ' UNION ALL ';
    END IF;
    statement := statement || 'select \'' || row.tab || '\' as table_name, count(*) as table_count from ' || row.tab ;
    union_needed := true;
  END LOOP;
  RAISE NOTICE 'sql to execute: %',statement;
  open curs1 for execute statement;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Lastly we need to call the procedure and execute the cursor

```
call count_tabs('mycursor');
fetch 1000 from mycursor;
```

A few notes on this:

- This assumes you want the results as output on your bench.  If you want to create a table with the results this is doable in the same structure
- Since the FROM clause value(s) is unknown at compile time this needs to be done in 2 steps - create the query and then execute the query.
- I believe you can have the procedure walk this same cursor itself but doing this is exceptionally slow